# (aws-amplify / cognito) first name, last name and date of birth attributes to check if an account is associated with given values

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

By using Angular and aws-amplify, would it be possible to poll for an existing account in cognito if the only attribute that I am capturing are first name, last name and date of birth? This will pretty much void auth in a way.

Please note: Our application does not allow any new library to be imported. We are working with what we have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution to my specific problem. By using confirmSignUp, I can catch the result and add a conditional statement within its scope.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Certainly it is possible to write a piece of code which queries user pool and informs if there is a match.

**Alternative 1:**
Enable [Amplify AdminQueries API](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/admin/) and use [listUsers](http://%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html) to retrieve users. Command syntax allows using AttributesToGet and Filter to modify the query.

```
{
   "AttributesToGet": [ "string" ],
   "Filter": "string",
   "Limit": number,
   "PaginationToken": "string",
   "UserPoolId": "string"
}
```

**Alternative 2:**
If possible, use Cognito API directly. [@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/index.html) has the class ListUsersCommand. Its interface [ListUsersCommandInput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/interfaces/listuserscommandinput.html) has properties AttributesToGet and Filter which can be used to fetch desired results.

Comment: Hey Marko, Thanks for your response and I like the idea. Unfortunately, our system does not accept Cognito instances. We are running end-points from API provider and we rely on what has been given to us.

Comment: So you don't have access to AWS Cognito API. Do you have access to AWS Amplify API? In order to query existing users you should definitely have an access to API with capabilities to query users.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I have found a good solution to my problem. This is by using confirmSignUp from Auth of AWS-Amplify.